# Devise Model Shoulda Validation: Email can't be blank (I'm not testing Email)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I got a Devise model called Candidate.

And I got this test:

```
it { expect(subject).to validate_presence_of(:democracyengine_recipient_id) }
```

And this line in the model:

```
validates :democracyengine_recipient_id, presence: true
```

And the validation works (in other tests).

But in this particular test I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: it { expect(subject).to validate_presence_of(:democracyengine_recipient_id) }
Expected errors to include "can't be blank" when democracyengine_recipient_id is set to nil, got errors: ["email can't be blank (\"\")", "password can't be blank (nil)"]
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`presence: true` is an ActiveRecord validator and in my opinion it should have been called as below : (NOTE: validates and not validate)

```
validates :democracyengine_recipient_id, presence: true
```

`validate` method adds a validation method or block to the class. This is useful when overriding the validate instance method becomes too unwieldy and you're looking for more descriptive declaration of your validations.
See more details in [API Documentation for validate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validate)

For `validates` see official [API Documentation for validates](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates)